# What type of boat is this with a single mast and a square sail?

Tags: boats, sea, gear-identification

What type of boat might this be? Or what category of boats would it fall under?

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the image?

Comment: The internet @CharlieBrumbaugh

Comment: TGO shouldn't be used like a crowd-sourced search engine, frankly.

Comment: @GabrielC. I’m sure I don’t understand you

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh if you must know: https://www.reddit.com/r/sailing/comments/3xovw0/orders_from_captain_during_thunderstorm/

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I meant that you could easily have found this information by using Google, especially since after visiting your link, the ship name is in the original post and the whole thread is about cogs...

Comment: But there is no loving TGO community on google

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel See, I had never even had to look up this information, so in order to answer you, all I had to do was to search myself, which I was able to do in less than 5 minutes. This task was not inaccessible to you.

Comment: I’m unsure how this applies to the great outdoors...

Comment: @JonCuster I wasn’t sure which SE it should go on. Which would you suggest?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is blatantly off-topic. The site is *for people who love being outdoors enjoying nature and wilderness, and learning about the required skills and equipment. It is about activities that occur in the Great Outdoors*, not about just any object that exists outside. Try [history.SE]

Comment: @JanDoggen I must’ve gotten confused because of the boat tags

Comment: Most likely, particularly given the answers, is the History SE.

Comment: @JanDoggen This question is not _blatantly_ off-topic. It is _arguably_ off-topic which is very different. Asking questions about boating very much is on topic. This question is not purely historical in nature since "what kind of boat has 1 mast and a square sail" is still applicable today. The only thing that makes it historical is the picture and reference to _that specific_ boat, which might not get any use from non-historians, but even then I'm not sure. At best, this is a corner case which is difficult to judge, but it is definitely not "_blatantly_" off-topic.

Comment: Dr. Shmuel, I want to welcome you here! You're right there's no loving TGO on Google, but there's a loving TGO here, and I should have made you feel valuable here because you are!  I apologize for skipping that part! Even though I voted to close this, I didn't feel as strongly as the words in the close reason, and I may have been wrong. I'll give it some more thought. In the meantime, no matter what happens, I hope it doesn't keep you from posting here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a **cog**,

> A cog is a type of ship that first appeared in the 10th century, and was widely used from around the 12th century on. Cogs were clinker-built, generally of oak, which was an abundant timber in the Baltic region of Prussia. **This vessel was fitted with a single mast and a square-rigged single sail.**

[Cog (ship)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cog_(ship))

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Modell_der_Bremer_Kogge_von_1380.jpg)

Comment: Amusingly (to me at least), your image is Carvel not Clinker built.

Comment: @Separatrix Good eye. The same goes for the image in the original question as well. I wonder if that is artistic license to make the image look better, or some other reason. Of course, people used the methods they knew or had resources for, so despite our linear thinking there were probably examples of both, even if one way was dominant.

Comment: @Aaron I believe they're both models rather than just images. With modern materials carvel is easier to model than clinker

Comment: @Separatrix Yes, first one I assumed was a computer-generated 3D model, possibly second one too. And yes: smooth surfaces are easier to model than non-smooth. In the 3D graphics field, it is one of our (not so well kept) secrets that we cut corners in places we don't think people will pay much attention. Might sound bad, but most 3D cgi is for games, real-time (or close) processing is necessary, and cutting corners allows the PC to keep up too. ;)  A PC can render a smooth model way faster. Maybe these were game models. Sorry Charlie for off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a military Cogue/Cog/Koggen with fore and aft archery towers. Cogues are the only medieval single mast square rigged sailboats of this style.